# can't push file in sdcard in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I want to insert images in sdcard, I am trying through command line

```
adb push a.png/sdcard/a.png
```

But it's not working, I can't even see any sdcard in ddms.

Comment: you might want to ask this question on: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check if your sdcard isn't mounted as external disk on your PC. If it's the case, no wonder you can't write to it through Android.

Answer (score 0):

create an sdcard while creating avd.